# Opening a Slack modal view when a user clicks a link in a message

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm currently building an app that would detect specific keywords in a slack message (channel or DM) and will highlight these words (by using an hyperlink markdown).

Although I'm facing an issue, I'd like to open a Slack modal view when a user clicks a click. If I understand properly the click should fire an event with a `trigger_id` and then I can use this idea to fire the `views.open` event and open the modal.

My question is if clicking a link (the highlighted word) can be an entry point for an user interaction with the app. If not is there a way to generate this event (and the `trigger_id`)?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer on Slack community channel. It's not possible to open a modal on a link click. This is not a supported action at the moment.